# Does Stationarity for Time Series extend to Independent Variables?

Tags: regression, time-series, stationarity

There have been many questions about the importance of stationarity and also its means of calculation here on CV, but one question that I have not seen an answer to is whether or not stationarity (in the context of a time series regression) is required for both the independent (X) variables, or is just required for the dependent (Y) variables.

Many thanks for someone who can elucidate this question!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stationarity should be sought for both to avoid any spurious correlations (that some or all variables actually just increase/decrease over time, independent of other factors), and there are methods of correction that can be applied to the entire model (i.e., including a trend as a DV) or just to specific variables (i.e., taking first differences of non-stationary variables) to address this if it is a problem.

Level variables are frequently violated by non-stationarity; for example, the number of Internet users in the world or the amount of pollution generally continually increase. So, if you have one of those as either independent or dependent variable, it will cause an issue. Non-stationarity both inflates t-statistics and biases betas. Including a trend often helps to control for that (so that you can say "the effect of the number of Internet users on Y, **controlling for time**, is predicted to be..."). And again, first differences of the specific variable at fault is also an option.

Comment: Nope. It depends on what kind of model you are using. The Single-equation generalized error correction model is agnostic with respect to the stationarity/integration of the predictor variables. See for example, Banerjee, A., Dolado, J. J., Galbraith, J. W., and Hendry, D. F. (1993). *Co-integration, error correction, and the econometric analysis of non-stationary data*. Oxford University Press, USA, or De Boef, S. and Keele, L. (2008). Taking time seriously. *American Journal of Political Science*, 52(1):184–200.

Comment: @Alexis In page 46 of the book you mention, (beginning of chapter 2 where the error-correction model is introduced) the authors write: "the variables used in this chapter may all be treated as being stationary, but (...) the same results apply if the variables are co-integrated". This is obviously not at all "agnostic with respect to stationarity/integration of the predictor variables", as you write in your comment above.

Comment: ""in order to have that relationship between two variables, both must be cointegrated” (Heo 1996, 488–89). This conclusion is misguided; the appropriateness of ECMs need not be linked to cointegration and the existence of equilibrium is independent of the model. Indeed all stationary time series models specify an equilibrium relationship."de Boef and Keel 2008. I don't have a copy of Banerjee handy this minute.

Answer (score 4):

Assume you have time series on a variable $Y$ and on a variable $X$, say both non-negative, and based on some idea of yours you believe that there is a reasonable argument that they can be linked by a linear relationship

$$y_t =  \beta x_t + u_t \tag{1}$$

Now say that your theoretical argument is basically sound, but it captures how $Y$ relates to $X$ *around a positive deterministic time trend*, denote it $d_t =1,2,...$. In reality therefore, the true relationship is

$$y_t =  \beta x_t + \gamma d_t + v_t \tag{2}$$

where $v_t$ has all the nice properties.

But you are impatient, you don't even graph the series to see how they evolve over time, and you go on and estimate model $(1)$ by OLS. You will obtain

$$\hat \beta = \frac {\sum_{t=1}^Tx_ty_t}{\sum_{t=1}^Tx_t^2}$$

and inserting the true equation $(2)$ for $y_t$ into this, you will get

$$\hat \beta  = \beta + \frac {\gamma\sum_{t=1}^Tx_id_t +\sum_{t=1}^Tx_tu_t}{\sum_{t=1}^Tx_i^2}$$

Consider the expected value of the estimator conditional on the regressor series

$$E(\hat \beta \mid X) = \beta + \frac {\gamma\sum_{t=1}^Tx_id_t }{\sum_{t=1}^Tx_i^2}$$

which explodes as $t$ increases since $d_t$ increases, going away from the true value of the parameter. This happens because the estimator is forced to incorporate the existence of the time trend into the estimate of $\beta$. In practice if you start with a sample of length $T$ and then gradually increase the sample length, you will see the OLS estimate of $\beta$ to increase also, making the whole estimation useless.

This is the most basic example to show that stationary and non-stationary data "don't mix".

> It would be instructive to work the reverse case. Assume that $y_t$ is
>   stationary, and you try to regress it on a time trend. Say, the true
>   model is
>
> $$y_t = \alpha + v_t$$ but you specify and estimate
>
> $$y_t = \alpha + \gamma d_t + u_t$$
>
> What will happen here?

**ADDENDUM**
Responding to conversation in the comments, the essence of the answer above is that if some of our data series are stationary, and some non-stationary, putting them together through an estimation algorithm will not provide meaningful results.

*But*, there exist techniques to *transform* the data series so that they become stationary, and then we can execute estimation (since now all *data series* involved in the estimation have become stationary), and obtain meaningful results. Detrending or Differencing a non-stationary series is the most usual such technique.

Moreover, there exists the phenomenon of co-integration, where, say, two stochastic processes are both non-stationary, but there exists a vector of constants that makes their linear combination weighted by this vector a stationary process. In such cases, regressing the one non-stationary series on the other non-stationary series provides meaningful results, and in some cases it is even to be preferred from the alternative approach, i.e. to, say, differencing both series to make them both stationary.

Comment: Issues arising from the "mixing" of integrated $Y$ and (potentially) non-integrated predictors depends on one's choice of model. See my comment to ShannonC. For example, models based on a *differenced* nonstationary dependent variable can have stationary predictors.

Comment: @Alexis Certainly, but these models do not include stationary and non-stationary time series any more, since I assume you mean that the differenced series has become a stationary stochastic process. If it hasn't, the issue that I showcase in my answer stands. The usual saying "a stochastic process that has been made stationary by differencing", is in my opinion confusing, since the transformation creates a new stochastic process.

Comment: That is a very fair point. I think it is useful to recognize that while modeling $Y$ against $X$ may be problematic, modeling $\Delta Y$ against $X$ may not have such problems. (ALso: I hope to get to a copy of Banerjee in the next few days so I can better understand where I am miscommunicating or misinterpreting on my other comment. :)

Comment: @Alexis I fully agree. It is important to clearly distinguish between "mixing" stationary and non-stationary data series in an estimation procedure, from the fact that "workarounds" like differencing do exist, that permit us to eventually conduct meaningful inference. I think I will add something related to this aspect in my answer, including also co-integration.

Answer (score 2):

Stationarity means, among other things, that a

- All the random variables $X_t$ have the same distribution
- All *pairs* of random variables $(X_t, X_s)$ have a joint distribution that depends only on the difference $t-s$ and not on the
  individual values of $t$ and $s$: the joint distribution of $(X_1,X_3)$ is the
  same as the joint distribution of $(X_2,X_4)$.
- More generally, the $n$-th order
  distributions of $(X_t, X_s, X_u, \ldots, )$ are the same as the $n$-th order
  distributions of the random variables 
  $(X_{t+\tau}, X_{s+\tau}, X_{u+\tau}, \ldots, )$

If the $X_t$ are all *independent* random variables, then the first of
the above conditions is *not* satisfied unless we also say, claim, assert,
or have reasons for believing, that all the $X_t$ have the *same* distribution.
This is often referred to in abbreviated fashion as iid or i.i.d. which
stands for *independent and identically distributed* random variables.
In this case, all the other conditions are automatically satisfied.
In other words,

> If the random variables constituting the process or time series are
>   iid random variables, then the process is stationary. If the random
>   variables are independent but not necessarily identically distributed,
>   then the process is non-stationary.

Comment: I think the question is about "independent variables" as in predictors, rather than random variables that are mutually independent. (Note the mention of "independent ($X$)" and "dependent ($Y$)" variables)

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate - although I was referring to the need for stationarity in both the X and Y variables, your exposition is actually very helpful as well for providing thoughts in a different dimension.